# How to prevent this background animation from 'jumping'

Tags: ios, css

As you can see, this background will animate down. I have everything I want working correctly except after the animation finishes, it makes this jump which I don't want. I just want it endlessly scroll without having that jump to it. CodePen Below.

Any suggestions on how to just keep making it scroll without that jump after about 10s

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEpJVL

```
<div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: 0 400px;}
}

@keyframes backgroundScroll {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: 0 400px;}
}
div{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3405/3582443182_80cf2d4f23.jpg') repeat-y;
  -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 10s linear infinite;
  animation: backgroundScroll 10s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background position in the final keyframe must match the height of the image, in this case 375px:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 375px;
  }
}
@keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 375px;
  }
}
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3nOs.png') repeat-y;
  -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 10s linear infinite;
  animation: backgroundScroll 10s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```